# Visual Studio Windows Form Size Problem

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, forms

I'm new to Visual Studio 2010 and I just figured out that the maximum size of the forms that can be created is 1292x812. I need to have many text boxes for the information I needed. However, the size of the form is too small that I can hardly see spaces for other text box. Is there a way to create a form with a scroll bar in it so that even though I have many text boxes it will be access in one form and not to create another form? Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the max size that you're being allowed is related to the size of your desktop area: My VS2010 just allowed me up to 5132x1092 which would roughly tie with my 3 monitors.

You should size the form so that it looks sensible if you resize your desktop to a common res such as 1024x768, otherwise it'll be too big for the screen for some users.

If you've got that much information you should break it down into logical groups, then use Tabs, or SubForms to show the data.

Putting too much info on one form makes it impossible for the user, and results in monster amounts of code behind the form which is hard to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum size of the form is limited by the resolution of the screen on which your developing on.

To answer your question, you work around this issue by dropping a Panel control onto the form and sizing it to whichever size you want. All of your controls are then placed on this panel control rather than the form directly. The panel will automatically add scroll bars as needed.

That said, what you are attempting to do is considered one of the classic "bad ideas" in UI design. When you create a screen like this you're asking the user to process more information than the brain could possibly digest. You question suggests you want to add hundreds of text boxs to a form while the user would feel overwhelmed by 10.

Please take a look at http://www.joelonsoftware.com and read his articles on UI design. They are the best starting point for any new programmer working with UI.

Answer (score 0):

Add a bigger panel to the form and set a scrollbar.